# powershell script to remove shared printers if exist

Tags: powershell, printer

sorry for ask guys but need some help to get this. I got some printers installed in many computers like \server\printer. I was thinking to remove them with a powershell script but cant get it done. I was thinking in something like this:

```
$printers=Get-Printer | where { $_.Type -eq 'Connection'} | select name /* this part show me only \\server\printers */
$printers | ForEach-Object {
    if ($printers) {
            Remove-Printer -Name $printers -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Thanks in advace to all.

Comment: Might be better to use Group Policy Preferences for this for multiple computers and users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are providing the whole list of printers to the Remove-Printer cmdlet. You have to provide one printer at a time.

```perl
[...]
Remove-Printer -Name $printers -Confirm:$false
# Error here------------/\
[...]
```

You are inside the foreach loop, you can get the current printer by using `$PSItem` or the short alias `$_`.
`$PSItem` (and `$_`) means "the current object in the ForEach loop"

This should work:

```perl
$printers=Get-Printer | where { $_.Type -eq 'Connection'} | select name /* this part show me only \\server\printers */
$printers | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_) {
            Remove-Printer -Name $_.Name -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! i didnt saw the error...have a nice week!